# Regex or jQuery to do find/replace with iteration count

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I have a tinymce based document that I need to do a find/replace on.

The markup in the document will have specific `<!--nextpage-->` comment tags in the html like so:

```
<p>some content</p><!--nextpage-->
<p>some more content</p><!--nextpage-->
```

I need to do a scripted find/replace that iterates over each occurrence of `<!--nextpage-->` in the markup and replaces it with an anchor element.

The anchor needs to have a sequential id value of "anchor+N" where `N` is the index of the anchor in the document plus 1.

So, for the above text, the replacement would yield:

```
<p>some content</p><a id="anchor1"></a>
<p>some more content</p><a id="anchor2"></a>
```

Can jQuery do this or do I need to use something else like regex?

Comment: Yes this can be done with **jQuery**

Comment: Using "regex" and "html" in the same sentence (/title) is going to cause you much grief. :)

Comment: Funny I had just finished editing the title as you were writing your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the `innerHTML` of the `body` and do a replace on that, writing the new text back after you are done.

---

[**DEMO - 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/2KJmC/) - Replace HTML using JavaScript

---

Though the code works, replacing the HTML can have consequences. If you have any events bound to any of the elements inside the `body` they will be unbound now as you have replaced the HTML.

If possible, if you have any influence over it I would not use `<!--nextpage-->` as placeholder but maybe an empty element you can target with a selector, maybe something like `<div class="nextpage-placeholder"></div>` for example.

That way you can target and replace only the specific elements, not effecting the rest of the code.

---

[**DEMO - 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/AhBQ6/) - Replace elements using jQuery

---

Another way would be to possibly just assign the class to the actual `p` tag and simply use jQuery `after` to add the anchors.

---

[**DEMO - 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/EuNtn/) - Append new anchors using jQuery

---

---

#### Code from DEMOs incase the fiddles go dead

---

*DEMO - 1*

```
<p>some content</p><!--nextpage-->
<p>some more content</p><!--nextpage-->
```

```
var text = document.body.innerHTML;
var targetText = "<!--nextpage-->";
var index = 1;

while(text.indexOf(targetText) > -1){
    text = text.replace(targetText, '<a id="anchor' + index + '"></a>');
    index++;
}

document.body.innerHTML = text;
```

---

*DEMO - 2*

```
<p>some content</p><div class="nextpage-placeholder"></div>
<p>some more content</p><div class="nextpage-placeholder"></div>
```

```
var $elements = $(".nextpage-placeholder");

$elements.each(function(index){
    $(this).replaceWith('<a id="anchor' + (index+1) + '"></a>')
});
```

---

*DEMO - 3*

```
<p class="nextpage-placeholder">some content</p>
<p class="nextpage-placeholder">some more content</p>
```

```
var $elements = $(".nextpage-placeholder");

$elements.each(function(index){
    $(this).after('<a id="anchor' + (index+1) + '"></a>')
});
```